# Forest, how to specify distance between levels

Tags: forest

I have this code, but want to reduce the distance between the levels. Any suggestions?

```
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        draw,
        fill,
        minimum width=2pt, % size
        inner sep=0pt,
        parent anchor=center,
        child anchor=center,
        s sep+=25pt, % distance between children
        grow = north
    }
[ 
[
[]
]
]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please complete your code?

Answer (score 3):

The level distance can be adjusted using keys `l` and `l sep`. For details, see the sections 3.7.2 (reference) and 2.4 (tutorial) of the manual.

Comment: You expect people to read the documentation? Oh my!

Comment: To misuse and abuse the comment space, given the frozen status of the Forest chat room: I don't suppose you have any ideas about http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340348/conflict-tikz-externalisation-local-bounding-box-with-empty-name-forked-edges do you?

Comment: A fast link to the manual: https://mirror.physik.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf